# How to decline user authentication request depending on its ip address in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

In my case some of users can login only from specific ip addresses (one for each user).

I need to decline all auth requests for a user if user's ip address doesn't match with ip from database.

For now I have this User entity:

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    // ....
    protected $id;

    // ....
    protected $allowedIp;
}
```

This check needs to be done at the authentication stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use an authentication voter. The Symfony cookbook has a recipe for an [IP blacklist voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html), so you can follow their example and change the code to deny if it's *not* on the list, instead of denying if it is.

Comment: Voters really work at authorization layer, but i think there is no better solution for now :(